# Noob AS3 question regarding using event handlers to remove MovieClip object from stage

Tags: actionscript-3, event-handling, removechild

I'm an AS3 noob just trying to get more comfortable working with event handlers in Flash and build interactivity into my application.

In the code below, I have created an instance of the DrawLineChart class called LineChart1.  When I test the movie, it shows up on the stage just fine and when I click on it, I can use a trace command to get a string statement written to the output window.

However, now I want to be able to click on LineChart1 on the stage and have it be removed.  When I do that, I get an error message 1120: Access of undefined property LineChart1.

Could someone please explain to me why I'm unable to refer to my instance LineChart1 and what I need to do so that I can refer to it and remove it when it gets clicked?  Also, I'd love to know why the trace statement works when I click on LineChart1 during runtime, but not the removechild command.

I'm sorry if this question is too simple, but thank you all for your help in advance.  I really appreciate it.

```
package{
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;

public class Main extends MovieClip{ 

var recWidth:Number = 250;
var recHeight:Number = 550;
var recX:Number = 50;
var recY:Number = 50;
var recScaleY:Number = 30;

public function Main(){

var LineChart1 = new DrawLineChart(recX, recY, recWidth, recHeight, recScaleY);
LineChart1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickHandler);
addChild(LineChart1);
}

function onClickHandler(e:Event):void{
trace("hello"); // This works.  When I click on the LineChart1 MovieClip on the stage during runtime, I get "hello" as an output.
removeChild(LineChart1); // throws an error 1120: Access of undefined property LineChart1.  Why?  
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable is scoped locally to `Main`, you need to declare it as an instance variable (class level), to properly define its scope.

```
private var _lineChart1:DrawLineChart; 

//main function
_lineChart1 = new DrawLineChart(...

//handler function
this.removeChild(_lineChart1);
```

For more information about scope in AS3 = check out the [livedocs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=03_Language_and_Syntax_21.html).

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have defined LineChart1 as a local variable. This means that because you declare it inside a function, it is only visible within that function.

Make `LineChart1` a property of your class, then you will be able to see it from your event handler. Alternatively, use `e.target as DrawLineChart`.

Answer (score 0):

All answer's is good but if u have more then one on the stage what can u do ?
You can use an Array to take a list of your mc's and then u can use that Array to remove mc's on the stage.
Here is a Simple Example:

```
  package
 {

    import flash.display.*;

    import flash.events.*;

    public class Main extends MovieClip{ 

    private var recWidth:Number = 250;
    private var recHeight:Number = 550;
    private var recX:Number = 50;
    private var recY:Number = 50;
    private var recScaleY:Number = 30;
    private var lineArray:Array = new Array();

    public function Main()
    {
        for(var i:int = 0;i<10;i++)
        {
            var LineChart1 = new DrawLineChart(recX, recY, recWidth, recHeight, recScaleY);
            LineChart1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickHandler);
            LineChart1.name = line+i.toString(); // u can use whatever u want for name's
            lineArray.push(lineChart1);
            addChild(LineChart1);
        }
        //if u want to place this 10 LineChart1 u can set x and y values like recX += recX and ect.
    }
    private   function onClickHandler(e:Event):void
    {
        //when u click one of your LineChart1 and want to remove it from stage u can use this
        trace(e.currentTarget.name); // if u want to see what is the name of ur mc
        var myId:String = e.currentTarget.name.substring(4,10);
        removeChild(getChildByName("line"+myId));
    }
}
```

hope it works for u